# Multiple ng-repeat on a single view

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, web-services, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show a table made from a JSON from a web service and then I makes an array. The array length is 0 and when I click a button I add 1 element to array and add a new row to the table. When I click on the button doesn't adds me the element on the array and don't know why. It's possible to have 2 different ng-repeat on the same controller and view?

There is the controller:

```
assets.controller('EditaTipusCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
                $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/getDetails/' + $routeParams.id).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.atrb = data;
                });

                $scope.nousAtributs = [];

                $scope.addNewLine = function () {
                    var newRow = {
                        "nomAtribut": "",
                        "tipus": "",
                        "mida": '',
                        "prioritat": "",
                        "obligatori": "",
                        "observacions": "",
                        "nomTipusActiu": $routeParams.id // nom del tipus d'actiu
                    };
                    $scope.nousAtributs.push(newRow);
               //     return $scope.nousAtributs;
                }

            });
```

And the view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div ng-controller="EditaTipusCtrl" id="test">
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-default" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="addNewLine()"></span>
                Afegir atribut
            </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table class="table">
            <tr>   
                <th>#</th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'ordre'; reverse = !reverse">Prioritat</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'nomAtribut'; reverse = !reverse">Atribut</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'midaAtribut'; reverse = !reverse">Mida</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'atributObligatori'; reverse = !reverse">Obligatori</a></th>
                <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'observacions'; reverse = !reverse">Observacions</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb">
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" ng-model="value.ordre" value="value.ordre" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.nomAtribut" value="value.nomAtribut" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.midaAtribut" value="value.midaAtribut" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.atributObligatori" value="value.atributObligatori" ng-true-value="'Si'" ng-false-value="'No'" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.observacions" value="value.observacions" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="a in nousAtributs">
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" ng-model="a.ordre" value="a.ordre" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.nomAtribut" value="a.nomAtribut" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.midaAtribut" value="a.midaAtribut" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a.atributObligatori" value="a.atributObligatori" ng-true-value="'Si'" ng-false-value="'No'" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.observacions" value="a.observacions" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
        <button class="btn btn-default" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Guardar
        </button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Solved:

I put the ng-click on the button tag instead the span tag

Regards

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? The properties you are setting on `newRow` don't seem to match the properties you are trying to output in your table. For example, your first column has `ng-model="a.ordre"`, but there is no "ordre" property on the `newRow` object you are creating.

Comment: I put the ng-click on the button tag instead the span tag. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-click should be in the button tag not the span

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do requires `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. So you would have;

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in atrb">
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="value.ordre" value="value.ordre" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.nomAtribut" value="value.nomAtribut" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.midaAtribut" value="value.midaAtribut" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value.atributObligatori" value="value.atributObligatori" ng-true-value="'Si'" ng-false-value="'No'" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="value.valor" ng-model="value.observacions" value="value.observacions" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none;" ng-repeat-end></tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="a in nousAtributs">
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="a.ordre" value="a.ordre" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.nomAtribut" value="a.nomAtribut" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.midaAtribut" value="a.midaAtribut" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="a.atributObligatori" value="a.atributObligatori" ng-true-value="'Si'" ng-false-value="'No'" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="a.valor" ng-model="a.observacions" value="a.observacions" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none;" ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: The OP's use of `ng-repeat` is correct and does not require `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.